# Gaussian function × cosine function

Tags: gaussian-integral

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(x) dx$$

I got to the following

$$\Re[\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-{i\over2})^2}.e^{1\over4}dx]$$

How I proceed further ?

Comment: Start by writing

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(x)\,dx=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(x)\,dx$$

Then, applying Euler's formula we have

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(x)\,dx=\frac12 \text{Re}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-1/4}e^{-(x-i/2)^2}\,dx$$

Finally, exploiting Cauchy's integral theorem, we find that 

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(x)\,dx=\frac12 \sqrt\pi e^{-1/4}$$

Comment: Thanks I got it

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.